# How to use PHP string endsWith to skip files from read?

Tags: php, arrays, string, filenames, glob

I want to simple skip files with filename that ends with "@2x" and implement in this code:

```
$fullres = glob("gallery/*.*");
        for ($i=0; $i<count($fullres); $i++)

            {                           
                $num = $fullres[$i];                        
                echo '<a href="'.$num.'" ><img src="/slir/?w=60&amp;h=80&amp;c=3x4&amp;q=85&amp;i=/'.$num.'" alt=""  /></a>';
            }
```

Is it actually possible?

Comment: yes it is but why you want to do that?

Comment: The code chunk does not show any attempt from your side to solve it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use `substr()` cuz than you are assuming that file name won't have any periods, instead use `pathinfo`

```
<?php

$fullres = glob("gallery/*.*");
foreach($fullres as $num) {
$fetch_file_name = pathinfo($num); //Fetch the file name with extension
$match_str = substr($fetch_file_name['filename'], -3); //Crop the file name

   if($match_str != '@2x') {
      echo '<a href="'.$num.'" ><img src="/slir/?w=60&amp;h=80&amp;c=3x4&amp;q=85&amp;i=/'.$num.'" alt=""  /></a>';
   }
}
?>
```

Comment: this one worked, but it has missing "}" at the end. ;)

Comment: @user2396523 Sorry, just missed that when I was editing, thanks for drawing my attention :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is you can use substr();

```
if(substr($num, -3) == '@2x') continue;
```

add this line after $num is defined.

Also you can simplify your code

```
<?php

 $fullres = glob("gallery/*.*");
 foreach($fullres as $num)
 {
     if(substr($num, -3) == '@2x') continue;
     echo '<a href="'.$num.'" ><img src="/slir/?w=60&amp;h=80&amp;c=3x4&amp;q=85&amp;i=/'.$num.'" alt=""  /></a>';
 }

?>
```

Solution using **DirectoryIterator**

```
<?php

foreach (new DirectoryIterator('gallery/') as $fileInfo) {
    if($fileInfo->isDot() || substr($fileInfo->getFileName(), -3) == '@2x')) continue;
    echo '<a href="'.$fileInfo->getFilename().'" ><img src="/slir/?w=60&amp;h=80&amp;c=3x4&amp;q=85&amp;i=/'.$fileInfo->getFilename().'" alt=""  /></a>';
}

?>
```

Comment: but this only cause that file's link not show. and don't prevents file read.

Comment: so why don't use use DirectoryIterator? What you want to achieve?

Comment: I would suggest using FilesystemIterator (or perhaps, GlobIterator), rather than DirectoryIterator.

Answer (score 0):

An option is to filter the array returned from `glob()` using [`preg_grep()`](http://php.net/preg_grep).

```
$fullres = glob("gallery/*.*");
$files = preg_grep('/@2x$/', $fullres, PREG_GREP_INVERT);
foreach ($files as $num)
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here

$fullres = glob("gallery/*.*");
for ($i = 0; $i < count($fullres); $i++) {
    $num = $fullres[$i];
    $info = pathinfo($num);
    $file_name =  basename($num,'.'.$info['extension']);
    if(substr($file_name, -3) != "@2x"){
        echo '<a href="'.$num.'" ><img src="/slir/?w=60&amp;h=80&amp;c=3x4&amp;q=85&amp;i/'.$num.'" alt=""  /></a>';
    }    
}
```

Try this out